# Voltage clamping for 28V nominal circuit

Tags: over-voltage-protection, diode-clamp

I am using a [Vishay SIP32430](https://www.vishay.com/docs/65223/sip32430.pdf) load switch for a 28VDC nominal input design. The absolute maximum rating for Vin is +30VDC. My input voltage will be nominal +28VDC, but short duration, low energy transient up to +35VDC may appear on the input, which in turn may damage the SIP32430.
Normally, I would use a diode to the supply and expect it to clamp to the supply voltage + the forward voltage of the diode.
But, because it is my supply voltage that may see the transient, I am not sure this would even work.
I am looking for circuit ideas on how to clamp the voltage to less than +30VDC, so as to be under the maximum rating, but still be able to operate at nominal +28VDC.

Comment: Pick another load switch. Even if you can't find one, it's not like you can't just build your own load switch either from discrete components.

Comment: As you state 28V is the nominal voltage. I would allow for about 20% or more over voltage which by design eliminates your part. Clamping to 30V is possible but more information is needed such as the impedance or amps available from your souorce and where the excess voltage (heat) will be spent when clamping.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I think that you are right, choosing another load switch is the simplest solution, even though it is it ideal for me. I will use the MAX14722 instead, which has a higher voltage rating.